# STL parallel execution vs. OpenMP performance

Tags: c++, stl, openmp

I'm starting a new project and would like to parallelize some computations. I've used OpenMP in the past, but am aware that now many STL algorithms can be parallelized directly. Since both approaches follow different paradigms (e.g. raw loops versus iterators and anonymous functions), I'd like to choose one up front.

Which is generally faster?

To test this I benchmarked the following C++20 code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
#include <execution>

template <class ExecutionPolicy>
int test_stl(const std::vector<double>& X, ExecutionPolicy policy) {
    std::vector<double> Y(X.size());
    const auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::transform(policy, X.cbegin(), X.cend(), Y.begin(), [](double x){
        volatile double y = std::sin(x);
        return y;
    });
    const auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto diff = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);
    return diff.count();
}

int test_openmp(const std::vector<double>& X) {
    std::vector<double> Y(X.size());
    const auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t i = 0; i < X.size(); ++i) {
        volatile double y = std::sin(X[i]);
        Y[i] = y;
    }
    const auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto diff = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);
    return diff.count();
}

int main() {
    const size_t N = 10000000;
    std::vector<double> data(N);
    std::iota(data.begin(), data.end(), 1);
    std::cout << "OpenMP:        " << test_openmp(data) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "STL seq:       " << test_stl(data, std::execution::seq) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "STL par:       " << test_stl(data, std::execution::par) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "STL par_unseq: " << test_stl(data, std::execution::par_unseq) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "STL unseq:     " << test_stl(data, std::execution::unseq) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled on my machine with GCC 10.3.0 (MSYS2), the OpenMP code consistently runs ~10 times faster:

```
OpenMP:        54719
STL seq:       628451
STL par:       638454
STL par_unseq: 494143
STL unseq:     506647
```

Is OpenMP faster in general (heuristically) for functionally equivalent code? Given the current state of development, might this change in the future?

Edit:

I'm building this benchmark using the follow `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)

add_executable(TEST main.cpp)
target_compile_features(TEST PRIVATE cxx_std_20)
set_target_properties(TEST PROPERTIES CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

find_package(OpenMP)
target_link_libraries(TEST PUBLIC OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
```

And then I compile it with the Windows Powershell commands:

```
cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"
mingw32-make
./TEST.exe
```

Comment: What happens if you switch the execution order? I suspect OpenMP Benchmark above uses X and Y arrays cached in the CPU.

Comment: Same result; the code I posted is abridged. In reality I have the two benchmarks in separate functions that take a const & to X and build their own Y's.

Comment: Obligatory query for any performance related question: Are you compiling with optimizations enabled? You should [edit] the question to include the compiler command.

Comment: Made that edit now, also including the full source code. Sorry, I'm still pretty naive

Comment: Have you tried to measure not paralleled std::transform version? Maybe it is just not getting paralleled at all? Maybe it requires `-pthread` flag to support threads or something. Also it could have higher threads startup/shutdown overhead - you can try to increase number of iterations, e.g. by x10 to check if the speed catches up.

Comment: I get similar numbers for the two loops, regardless of which order I run them in. (Compiling with MSVC, full optimizations on.)

Comment: Compiler explorer also gives [similar results](https://godbolt.org/z/banvWz57r)

Comment: Why do you use `volatile`? It is much harder for the compiler to apply some optimization with it.

Comment: dewaffled, according to the [g++ man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/g++), `-fopenmp` already implies `-pthread`. Adding that option doesn't make a difference for me. If I increase/decrease `N` by a factor of 10, I get the same result.

Comment: Jerome Richard, I used `volatile` to prevent any compiler trickery from optimizing away my benchmark, otherwise I might get a misleading result

Comment: The ironic thing about `volatile` is that is pretty much guarantees a misleading result.

Comment: Eljay, could you please explain why in this case?

Comment: Sorry all, I think this question was not well informed. See my edit including the results for the different policies; I think I'm having some compilation issue where the STL doesn't want to run parallelized.

Comment: `volatile` impact the benchmark as it is optimized in one case and not in another case (biased). This actually proves that the compiler can ignore it in this case. If you want the compiler not to optimize your benchmark, you need to read the produced value outside of the timed code. The usual solution is to perform a basic sum reduction of the array. The final value must be printed or stored somewhere so that the compiler must execute the code producing the array.

Comment: The parallel STL support is still not great yet by default. Clang apparently do not support is so far according to [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/17) and GCC require TBB so far (at least for GCC 9 and 10). Not to mention OpenMP is more flexible than STL algorithms and has a much better support for accelerators. OpenMP has a basic SIMD support, but the one of the STL is very limited and most non-trivial codes are not vectorized yet...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tested your code (just changing size_t to int in the openmp implementation) with MSVC in my windows 11 machine because I thought it was very strange to have almos all stl parallel with the same performance... The `seq` execution policy does not do parallelism at all... and in your test it was performing much close to the other execution policies...

So, I've compiled with this:

```
cl.exe /Zi /EHsc /nologo /std:c++latest /O2 /openmp /Fe: .\openmp-vs-exec-policy.exe .\openmp-vs-exec-policy.cpp
```

And my results were:

```
.\openmp-vs-exec-policy.exe
OpenMP:        14089
STL seq:       99299
STL par:       10659
STL par_unseq: 9811
STL unseq:     68051
```

In another tests of mine, stl performs better than openmp almost always...

So, my guess is that the stl you are using is not very well implemented or the GCC for windows does not do a good job compiling the stl...

[EDIT]

I was looking for g++ implementation of STL parallelism, and found out that it only works if you have the libtbb installed with it.

Just like OpenMP only works if you compile with `-fopenmp` and if it is not passed to the compiler everything falls back to sequential, STL implementation of execution policy falls back to sequential if you doesn't have the libtbb installed and it does not come by default in g++.

Comment: I have compiled the code using Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.31.31107 for x64 and just compared `STL par_unseq` and `OpenMP` 20 times in a loop. Based on the results STL par_unseq was just slightly faster:  `OpenMP: 8210 (+-754)`   and `STL par_unseq: 7693 (+-526)`, but it was easy to create an example where OpenMP was the faster one.

Comment: Sure, it depends on the hardware too... Mine is an Intel, but with AMD or ARM it could be very different... My point was to justify Nicks results. On the other hand, with co_routines, when STL give support to it, and mixing with the execution policy's, my bet it will be much more flexible and works better even in low available cores. But OpenMP is far more stable and supported... so, for production code today, I'd go with OpenMP.